# Apache Archiva 2.1.1 Upgrade: Proxy does not work

Tags: apache, upgrade, archiva

we try to upgrade from archvia `1.3.6` to `2.1.1` but suddenly the remote repositories (including proxy connectors) stopped working. The remote repository view shows error marks in the column "Remote check" but no error message is shown.

[image: Remote Check example]

Is there a possibility to find out what is going on?

We are using a proxy, we tried with proxy activated, deactivated. I even installed archiva locally on my machine with a fresh database, but still no success.

(how does this remote check even work when the proxy is activated/deactivated in the proxy connectors?)

Eclipse (with newest m2e) says `Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.9`. It goes so fast, that i don't think archiva is trying to reach the central-Repository.
The logs on archiva-side are empty.

Does anybody have some hints or the same problem? I think i will try it at home tonight, to see if it is a network issue.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

### Update

It really seems that the proxy connector does not work since the internal Repository is empty. `http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal/` only shows `.indexer`

### Update 2

The proxy configuration seems bugged in Archiva `2.1.1`. I can see the same behaviour as here: [Mailing List](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/archiva-users/201406.mbox/%3C09EAAF5478DA2641BA3B70E614B8F96F17AB925B@GAALPA1MSGUSRAB.ITServices.sbc.com%3E)

**A JIRA task for this would be nice.**

Does anybody know a workaround to set the proxy for a proxy connector? Or is there a possibility to set a global proxy via a settings file?

### Update 3

Rellay seems like a bug in archiva. I sent a mail to the mailing lists. Hopefully this is getting fixed soon because this is a blocker for every user with a proxy.

I won't delete this question for documentation if someone has the same problem. The issue can be found in JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRM-1861)

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem and the simple solution was to change the proxy protocol from "http" to "https".

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. On first glance the solution given by Christian Quast seemed to work, but it didn't solve the problem. I eventually used a work around by using JVM proxy settings:

- -Dhttp.proxyHost=[your_proxy_address]
- -Dhttp.proxyPort=[your_proxy_port]
- -Dhttp.proxyUser=[your_proxy_user_name]
- -Dhttp.proxyPassword=[your_proxy_user_password]
- -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|::0|[any_other_hosts_not_to_use_proxy]

### Update

I know it may sound weird but, using the settings above, the error/warning icon on "Remote Check" may still appear. If you add the "network proxy" (mine is using https protocol) to your remote repository (the error/warning icon is still there) but editing the remote repository again and removing it's "network proxy" will show the OK/sun icon.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `<networkProxy>` under `conf\settings.xml` gets updated correctly including the port information (probably because my port is not a default 8080) but remote repository connection is still failing.
Also, changing proxy protocol to https did not help.
I know the proxy is right because I use the same for maven `.m2\settings.xml`

Fortunately I am only evaluating open source repo management tools. Started with Archiva as it is by Apache and we use Maven in our project. Would have moved ahead if this critical issue had a fix or work around. Guess I will have to take a shot at Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same problem here. I can't vote on your BUG report because I have no jira account.

As far as I figured out there seems to be a problem with the configuration file `~/.m2/archiva.xml`. The Proxy is set without port information.

Hopefully this bug will be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: I added your diagnosis to the [JIRA issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-1861). By the way, you can create a JIRA account for codehaus [here](https://xircles.codehaus.org)

Comment: Hi, i'm using Archiva 2.1.1. I guess there still no fix for this bug reported in Jira  MRM-1861 : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-1861. even though i added the port number to my networkProxy <port>8080</port> in the ~/.m2/archiva.xml, it doesn't seem to work. Any solution ? thanks in advance.

Comment: As Oliver Lamy mentioned on [jira](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-1861), if the repository is `central` you have to use `https` instead of `http`. Can you give it a try? But I suspect it will have no impact to the proxy port.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the master branch of Archiva got the folowing conclusions:

The problem is caused by numerous classes that do not use the proxy configuration correctly and classes that use the proxy configuration of Maven and not the Archiva configuration.

The **ProxyInfo** class in many places does not configure the type of proxy connection, and then causes an error in the connection. The class **DownloadRemoteIndexTaskRequest** class uses an implementation of Maven (**IndexPacker**) to download content repositories and that does not use the Archiva configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Extending João Ferreira's reply, to access repositories with https URLs (such as Maven Central), you will also need:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=[your_proxy_host]
-Dhttps.proxyPort=[your_proxy_port]
```